# UIViews outside of View not touchable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm working on an iOS 7 app.

My `ViewController.view` is vertically draggable and snaps between 2 positions.
When I drag it up, the `ViewController`'s `center.y` property is at around -45.

Obviously, some of the objects inside the `ViewController.view` are positioned "out of bounds". The problem I have with those, especially one them being a `UITableView`, is that they don't seem to accept touches. I actually implemented:

`-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`

And in the area which is (originally) below the `ViewController.view`'s bounds, this method is not called on touch.

The objects are visible, I just can't interact with them. Everything that's originally located within the `ViewController.view`'s bounds works fine.

I tried setting the `ViewController.view.frame.size.height` to 1000 within `viewWillAppear`, but that didn't seem to work. I also tried to remove and add the objects again - that doesn't work.

Do I have to put everything into a separate view under `ViewController.view` or is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

I searched around and every example of touchesBegan I found moves a subview not the main view. When you implement touchesBegan on a view controller then it will only be called if it's top view has a touch event. So moving the view will move where the events will be caught.

A good solution would be a redesign of your layout so each subview can be dragged.

Also checkout the pan gesture. This guy has really good tutorials:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more